# HTML5/WebRTComm.js==>MMS on WSS: SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: webrtc

Given the new requirement that browsers no longer support voice/video over insecure origine(which is taking us we the developers to redo/undo/goback since none of the test environment workarounds is practical in A distributed environment),I have tried to switch to https and wss and I have configured MMS connector with the following.I am running a converged app with two tomcat instances:
1-Apache Tomcat v8.0 at localhost for the app embeding WebRTComm framework( WebRTComm.js and jain-sip.js etc..).https is working perfect in browser and in code for the app.
2-Mobicent Apache Tomcat v7.0 at localhost for the sipservlet for signalling and other need pre-session requirements.WSS is causing trouble at the server with no return from handshake.
this is the connector in Mobicent Apache Tomcat v7.0.

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
acceptCount="200" 
clientAuth="false" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain" 
compression="off" 
compressionMinSize="2048" 
connectionUploadTimeout="120000" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
enableLookups="false" 
keystoreFile=":\Developement\.....\ServerKeyStore\server.jks" // wonder why relative path(conf/ServerTrustStore\truststore.jks) is resolved but throw FileNoFoundExc in particular case.Any idea? 
keystorePass="xxxxxx" 
keyAlias="clientselfsigned"
maxKeepAliveRequests="200" 
maxThreads="250" 
maxSpareThreads="75" 
minSpareThreads="25"
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
port="8443" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true" 
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello" 
sslProtocol="TLS" 
truststorePass="xxxxxx" 
truststoreType="jks" 
truststorefile="D:\Developement\.....\ServerKeyStore\server.jks" // wonder why relative path(conf/ServerTrustStore\truststore.jks) is resolved but throw FileNoFoundExc in particular case.Any idea? 
/>
```

and this is the connector in Apache Tomcat v8.0 for the web app:

```
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"   
acceptCount="200"   
clientAuth="false"   
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain"   
compression="off"   
connectionUploadTimeout="120000"   
disableUploadTimeout="true"   
enableLookups="false"   
keystoreFile="D:\Developement\....\ServerTrustStore\truststore.jks"   
keystorePass="xxxxx"   
keyAlias="clientselfsigned"  
maxKeepAliveRequests="200"   
maxThreads="250"   
maxSpareThreads="75"   
minSpareThreads="25"  
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"  
port="8443"   
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"   
scheme="https"   
secure="true"   
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello"   
sslProtocol="TLS"   
truststorePass="xxxxxx"   
truststoreType="jks"   
truststorefile="D:\Developement\....\ServerTrustStore\truststore.jks" 
/>
```

Both configured my sip-stack and eclipse lunch configuration(run/debug) with :

```
gov.nist.javax.sip.TLS_CLIENT_AUTH_TYPE=Disabled  

javax.net.ssl.keyStore="D:\Developement\Projects\Sources\Pending\security\ServerKeyStore\server.jks"  

javax.net.ssl.trustStore="D:\Developement\Projects\Sources\Pending\security\ServerKeyStore\server.jks"  

javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxx  

javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxx  

javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS  
gov.nist.javax.sip.TLS_CLIENT_PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello

gov.nist.javax.sip.MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE=1048576  

javax.net.debug=ssl
```

.
I have also created the necessary keystore and clien truststore as can be seen above.
I have tried a variation of TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1 and see that the client(jain-sip.js) and MMS are both hapy with TLSv1.2. see ClientHello, TLSv1.2 and

```
ServerHello, TLSv1.2 as below:  
%% Initialized: [Session-13, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]  
%% Negotiating: [Session-13, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]  
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
```

and the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 was selected.
So when I click client.hml=>>TelScaleRTMController.js(onClickConnectButtonViewEventHandler)==>>this.webRTCommClient.open(this.webRTCommClientConfiguration);==>RegistrarSIPServlet.java,  TLS handshakes succeeds as I can get to my RegistrarSIPServlet.doRegister():
It is here that things go bad:As soon as it executes SipServletResponse.send();,it says:

```
NioSelector-WSS-172.62.2.10/5082, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, protocol_version  
NioSelector-WSS-172.62.2.10/5082, fatal: engine already closed. Rethrowing   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
NioSelector-WSS-172.62.2.10/5082, fatal: engine already closed. Rethrowing   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

.....

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SSLStateMachine.unwrap(SSLStateMachine.java:263)  
at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SSLStateMachine.unwrap(SSLStateMachine.java:198)  
at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.NioTlsWebSocketMessageChannel.addBytes(NioTlsWebSocketMessageChannel.java:215)  
at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.NioTcpMessageChannel.readChannel(NioTcpMessageChannel.java:117)
```

.....
the sip msg generated and received by the registrar is:
SIP message sent: REGISTER sip:pbx.server.com SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 1451477183409
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: sip:admin@pbx.server.com;tag=1451477183429
To: sip:admin@pbx.server.com
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS XNCrSBbscUch.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK-333430-45dd017fdcbb8f884bf0a78789902ae7;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: RoooterUAv1.0[admin-MOHAMMAD-125-1]-0
Expires: 3600
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,UPDATE,INFO,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,REFER,MESSAGE,OPTIONS
Contact: sip:admin@XNCrSBbscUch.invalid;transport=wss
Content-Length: 0

As you can see no SDP is generated as now and this is where we stop.
The client waits to timeout ....

One more,I have restriced to the same domain of my PBX, in my dar as:

```
INVITE=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0","REGEX=From:.sip:.@pbx.domain.com"),("project","DAR:From","TERMINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0","REGEX=From:.sip:.@pbx.domain.com")  
MESSAGE=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0")  
PUBLISH=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0")  
NOTIFY=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0")  
REGISTER=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0","REGEX=From:.sip:.@pbx.domain.com",("project","DAR:From","TERMINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0","REGEX=From:.sip:.@pbx.domain.com")  
REFER=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0")
SUBSCRIBE=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0")
OPTIONS=("project","DAR:From","ORIGINATING","","NO_ROUTE","0")
```

I will very much applreciate your ideas on understanding the problem and the solution.
Thank you !!

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to greet : Hi ALL !!!!!

Comment: Which version of MSS are you running ?

Comment: I am using mss-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-apache-tomcat-7.0.50.

Comment: Can you retry with a more recent version from https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/releases ?

Comment: OK. I will feed back on that soon.How about my client.Any necessary configs in websocket-b2bua (downloaded in 2014 and highlyed modified) to work with tls1.2 specifically TelScaleRTMController.js ,WebRTComm.js and jain-sip.js ?

Comment: I would recommend moving to latest version of webrtcomm and jain sip is all in the same repo at https://github.com/Mobicents/webrtcomm